# Can this circular dependency in TypeScript be refactored so separate TypeScript files are possible?

Tags: typescript, circular-dependency, circular-reference

I have those `TypeScript` classes in the same .ts file because there are import dependencies. I would appreciate if someone could help me refactor the code so I could remove the circular reference of imports:

The first one is the abstract `GenericModel` :

```
export abstract class GenericModel {
    nodeClass: string;
    id: string = "0";

    static fromJson(json: any): GenericModel {
        if (json.nodeClass === "Entity") {
            return EntityModel.fromJson(json);
        }
        else if(json.nodeClass === "User") {
            return UserModel.fromJson(json);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The other two classes are `EntityModel`(listed below) and `UserModel`:

```
export class EntityModel extends GenericModel {
    nodeClass: string = "Entity";
    alias: string;
    description: string;

    constructor(public text: string, public id: string, public uuid: string, alias: string, public rand:string = "") {
       //[...]
    }

    //instance methods
    //[...]

    public static fromJson(json: any): EntityModel {
        var entity = new EntityModel(json.text, json.id, json.uuid, json.alias, json.rand);
        entity.description = json.description;

        if (json.types) {
            for (let type of json.types) {
                let objectifiedType: EntityModel = EntityModel.fromJson(type);
                entity.types.push(objectifiedType);
            }
        }
        if (json.innerEntities){
            for (let innerEntity of json.innerEntities) {
                let objectifiedInnerEntity: EntityModel = EntityModel.fromJson(innerEntity);
                entity.innerEntities.push(innerEntity);
            }
        }
        return entity;
    }
}
```

What I am doing here is deserialization of JSON using a hierarchy of static calls `fromJson()` based on `nodeClass`.

It is obvious that if `GenericModel` was in a separate file it would need to import `EntityModel` and `UserModel`
while the other two if they were in separate file they would need to import `GenericModel`.

`GenericModel --- has to import --> EntityModel, UserModel`

`EntityModel --- has to import --> GenericModel`

`UserModel --- has to import --> GenericModel`

I wonder if there is a way to refactor the code so it does what it does now but also the classes are in separate .ts files.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is to isolate the circular dependencies into their own module. I would extract all the `fromJson` methods into a single, new module. Then I would convert `fromJson` into a class called something like `ModelFactory`, since this is now more similar to a factory pattern. So, the end result would look something like this:

```
export class ModelFactory {
  // maybe add a constructor for some configuration data, maybe not

  create(json: any) {
    ...
  } 
}
```

Now, I also see that you type the `json` object as `any`.  That seems to be bit broad when you seem to know at least a few properties on the type.  I'd try to create an interface for the json object, like this:

```
export interface ModelJson { // find a better name
  text?: string; 
  id?: number;
  uuid?: UUID; 
  alias?: string;
  rand?: number;
  ...
}

type UUID = number;
```

This is a more typescripty way of doing things.

Comment: Thanks! I had the feeling I would need to add a new class like the factory you suggested! Thanks for the tip of the interface/json :) Btw what is ```type UUID = number;``` at the end? Happy New Year!

Comment: That is just a type alias. When you have something like a UID that happens to be a number, but really it's just a technical detail and it has its own semantics, you often use a type alias. This ensures that you can only use UIDs where expected and you won't accidentally pass in a vanilla number.

Comment: for me the ```uuid``` is a string though! Can I still do: ```type UUID = string;```? Thanks

Comment: Of course. More information about type aliases are found here: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html In general, I mostly use type aliases for better documentation of parameters and properties. They are never fundamental to the application.